# Why didn't Vision damage the Quinjet in Civil War?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil war*'s airport fight scene, as depicted in [How It Should Have Ended](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fvLw021rVN0) (around 2:10) Vision could have just blown up the quinjet, stopping Capt and Bucky from escaping in it.

I searched for why he didn't, and instead chose to blow up a tower to block their path, only to have his block blocked by Wanda, and the only answer that made enough sense was from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-didnt-Vision-just-blow-up-the-ship-in-the-airport-fighting-sceen). The quinjet was Avengers/government property and cost a ton.

However, I want to reshape the question. **Why didn't Vision *damage* Quinjet?**

1. The tower blown up still has considerable cost, and they will have to pay for it.
2. He(?) didn't need to damage quinjet beyond repair. Flying is complicated, and I imagine some repairable damage  that doesn't cost as much as a quinjet would have stopped the ship from flying.

So, why didn't Vision do it? Is it due to lack of fighting experience (I doubt it)? Or is there something else I missed? Preferably an in-universe explanation please.

Comment: Fast jet fighters are expensive (from $30m for an elderly F-15 to $350m for an F-22).  A tower at an airport is for sure in the millions, but even a repair on an advanced aircraft might compete in cost.  Really the explanation is that they needed to get away for plot reasons.

Comment: Tower was the bigger and easy target which should surely block other guys' path to jet. compared to jet, tower costs much less

Answer (score 16):

Leaving aside the inherent "it's comics" explanations and that Cap & Co, *need* the quinjet to advance the plot....

> The tower blown up still has considerable cost.

Yes but rebuilding a fairly simple tower pales in comparison to the cost of a quinjet.

> ...and they will have to pay for it.

Actually, it's more likely Tony Stark would have to pay for it. He's the bankroll behind the Avengers and Vision is on *his side* so it would seem logical that he'd try the **"least cost option"**....assumiing that his battle tactics thought that far ahead.

For instance, a fairly recent tower in Charlotte NC cost around c$100m

> The FAA awarded a $60 million contract to build the new facility in January 2016 to Archer Western Construction.  Equipment, installation and training costs, and demolition of the old tower bring the total project cost to $112 million.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.faa.gov/news/press_releases/news_story.cfm?newsId=20415)</sup>

..whereas a modern jet fighter (considerably less advanced than a quinjet

> F-22’s would cost an estimated $339 million per aircraft, with a cost of around $150 per each additional unit.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.historyinorbit.com/30-facts-about-the-f-22-raptor-that-will-blow-you-away/)</sup>

---

> He didn't need to damage quinjet beyond repair. Flying is complicated, and I imagine some repairable damage that doesn't cost as much as a quinjet would have stopped the ship from flying.

Possibly true **if** Vision had full control....but, as we find out, **he doesn't** when he actually attempts to bring the Falcon down but manages to bring down War Machine instead...with disastrous consequences, at least for Rhodey.

Comment: Re the last point, isn't he aiming at Falcon rather than the Quinjet when he takes out Rhodey?

Comment: Good point edited..but the point remains the same...he's not perfect. :)

Comment: Actually, Rhodey ended up pretty OK, comparatively

Comment: @AzorAhai Rhodey ended up nearly paralysed! The last time we saw him he could only walk because of Stark tech

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional He should be hella ded.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional And he has recovered well enough to be back in War Machine armor for Avengers: Infinity War, which takes place just 2 or 3 years after he fell hundreds/thousands of feet to the ground while inside a metal can and was in a coma and then couldn't feel his legs for a while. *Comparatively*, he's doing great.

Comment: I assumed that the subject of 'comparatively' was some normal state, and not in fact death! *Comparatively*, we're all doing pretty great I guess;)

Comment: But $150M isn't that much more than $112M.

Comment: But it is more..and *logically* a computer based being would choose the lower figure...but a quinjet would undoubtedly cost considerably more than an F-22.